# Invalid command 'RemoteIPProxyProtocol' (httpd 2.4.6) when running httpd behind HAproxy in tcp mode

Tags: apache, load-balancing, haproxy, transparent

I'm trying to setup PROXY protocol between a HAproxy acting as a load-balancer (tcp mode) and httpd (2.4.6)running behind. The objective is to get the "real" client IP addresses on the httpd-side.

In haproxy.conf the keyword `send-proxy` has been put in the selected backend.

The line:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
```

has been added to httpd config file.

The directive `RemoteIPProtocolAddress On` has been set in the httpd virtualhost configuration file.

However, when reloading/restarting httpd the following errors appears:

```
[root@XXXXXXXXX conf.d]# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed
[...]
Invalid command 'RemoteIPProxyProtocol', perhaps misspelled ...
```

Looking at [the mod_remoteip source code for httpd 2.4.6](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.4.6/modules/metadata/mod_remoteip.c), it appears the directive `RemoteIPProxyProtocol` does not exist anymore.

I'm not sure to understand how the versioning works. For instance I can see the `RemoteIPProxyProtocol` directive exists in [mod_remoteip 2.4.43](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.4.43/modules/metadata/mod_remoteip.c) but not in [mod_remoteip 2.4.0](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.4.43/modules/metadata/mod_remoteip.c).

How can I workaround this issue ? E.g. compiling another mod_remoteip version ? Downgrading httpd? Other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to meet the same problem, and after checking the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html):

> RemoteIPProxyProtocol is only available in httpd 2.4.31 and newer

I'm currently running Apache/2.4.29 on Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache/2.4.41 on Ubuntu 20.04, it works with 2.4.41.

Comment: then I to configure to receive visitor's client ip instead of proxy node ip  on apache2.4.29 ?